# Expanded is hiding the other child in column

Tags: dart, flutter

When I write:

```
new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("hello"),
          new Text("hello"),
        ])
```

It works perfectly fine and shows two text widgets as intended.

I want to keep one text widget at bottom and take all the available space and another at top.

So, I wrote:

```
 return new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("hello"),
         new Expanded( child:  new Text("hello")),
        ]);
```

But now it is not showing text widget at bottom.

*Edit*
I want to draw following layout with background as Image..
I have a stack,
which has an image and row with text
and that row has column with two text widgets.
is there a mistake? How can I achieve it?
[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You mean that the text widget in the expanded widget isn't showing?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin Yes

Answer (score 0):

You're using a text as a child. According to the documentation you need to use a Column, Row or a Flex.

[Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Comment: I used Flexible. then also it is doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes, but Flexible is not the same as Flex. Try the Flex widget.

Comment: I have edited the question Can you please help me for the image I have shown?

Comment: Your edit seems like a different problem from the first one. If you have a different problem or question then you should post a new question.

Comment: Can you please help me? I am stuck. I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: Of course I can help you, but if you make this question your personal thread of issues regarding your app then it won't be very helpful for other people having the same issues as you. It's better to accept my answer if it helped you and make a new question.